# Define an array; sum the array; and display the result

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

I just need to solve my assignment this is the first question:

> Define an array that has 5numbers ( 1,1,2,3,2) then add these numbers to each other and display the answer:

I try to solve it like this, but I don't know how I can print the result

```
  .model small

  .stack 100h
.data
W dw 1,1,2,3,2
msg2 db 0ah,0dh,'$'

.code
main:
  mov ax,@data
  mov ds,ax


  xor ax,ax
  lea si,w
  mov cx,5

X: 
   add ax,[si]
   add si,2
 loop X



end main
```

and the second question is:

> Write a program that read 3 numbers from the user and stores it in the array then displays the even numbers in a new line.

How can I know the even number?

Comment: To display them you need to convert to text. If you can assume single digits that's pretty trivial to do. Also, plenty of examples for it do some research. As for checking even numbers, just examine the least significant bit.

Comment: I try to print the result from al and I write this code : 
mov dl,al       
mov ah,2h
int 21h
But didn't get the resul :((

Comment: Because you didn't convert to text.

Comment: how can I convert it to text? @Jester

Comment: I solve it :D : mov ah,2
mov dl,al
add dl, 48
int 21h
@Jester